# Arrange bootstrap column

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create in bootstrap something like this on [PICTURE](http://i43.tinypic.com/wv9uh5.png)

I create that left side but i can't create middle content.

I use `col-sm-12` and then `col-sm-3`. I can not  get thet rows on the page. I'm always page halved into two horizontal section and I want four vertical sections.

Here is fiddle of my code that you can easy know what i want [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yYSLD/2/) I only need that middle content to be like on picture.. 4 vertical columns and in that columns that i have 2 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some content to them.

**Try this:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">Left sidebar</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">Content</div>

</div>
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/yYSLD/)